# Count today's orders for a specific Postal Code in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am trying to put a limit on orders made on my Shopify Store for a day from a specific zip code. i.e I want to deliver 10 orders to a specific zip code in a day. I am hoping to achieve that on my Cart page because I can't edit checkout page (If I am right). I will get zip code on cart page to check the orders. If my orders threshold is completed the checkout button will be enabled otherwise it will remain disabled.

I have the algorithm in my mind but I don't know Shopify objects that good. I just need pointing to the right direction.

**My Broken Code:**

```
 {% assign ordersCount = 0 %}
    {% for orders in checkout.customer.orders %}
        {% if orderDate is today 
             and
         checkout.customer.orders.customer_address.zip == 
               {{user_entered_zipcode}}  %}
          ordersCount++
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if ordersCount >= 10 %}
     <p>Today's order limit for this area is reached.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve with Liquid is not possible. If you have a look at global [Liquid objects](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects), there is no object that will provide you the information about all the orders.

What you are trying to do, can be achieved in multiple ways. I will mention 2 solutions, that I just devised now.

**Using Private App**

Create a private app that exposes a public endpoint that you can query via AJAX from your Shopify cart page. In your private app, fetch order details via [Shopify REST API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference) or [GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference) and return true or false based on your conditions.

**Using Metafields**

Another approach is to listen to order create webhook and then in your webhook handler, add a metafield on [Shop resource](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-04). Metafield names can be something like ***order-count-{zipcode}*** where zipcode will be based on addresses and value will be the order count. Individual metafields can also be replaced with a single metafield whose value type would be **json_string**. Then render those metafields via Liquid in some JavaScript variables and compare it on frontend.

I would recommend the first approach as it is a pretty flexible solution.